# How to make a batch file to execute an action at the moment when a Window process is terminated?

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

I start a certain program with a batch file, and it triggers a sequence of very short processes within 1 second, the process to which I want to tie my action starts and then terminates almost immediately, it lasts milliseconds. Now my action is executed at the exact moment when this process starts. I do it by applying a loop:

```
start ProgramX.exe

:search
        tasklist | find "ProcessA.exe"
        if errorlevel 1 goto search

"execute action N"
```

What is the best way to make my batch file to execute an action at the exact moment when this process ENDS instead? Since I suspect "action N" may interfere with "ProcessA.exe", but I don't want ANY delay, I need the action to be executed **at the exact moment** when this process is terminated...

Sorry, I'm just a beginner and I couldn't find a definitive answer to my question.
There is a `/wait` command but it's used only when there is a `start` command before that, so far I couldn't find anything else...

Thank you!

---

**Update:**

I figured it out. It has to be like this:

```
start ProgramX.exe

:search
tasklist | find "ProcessA.exe"
if errorlevel 1 goto search

:search1
tasklist | find "ProcessA.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    "execute action N" 
) else (
    goto search1
)
```

This way action N is being executed after I ran ProgramX.exe, then ProcessA.exe starts and ends, it happens exactly at the moment ProgramX.exe has terminated. I tested it, and it works as intended.

Thanks to everyone who responded, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What is js tag doing there?

Comment: What you are doing is not good. The constant loops means that a processor is constantly busy looking at your process list. This wastes processor resources and energy. You should at least add a timeout-command within the loop to wait between each test.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Give us a bit more context, so that we can maybe find a better approach than polling the process list in a loop in a batch file

Comment: OK, I start a certain program with a batch file, and it triggers a sequence of very short processes within 1 second, the process to which I want to tie my action starts and then terminates almost immediately, it lasts milliseconds. Now my action is executed when this process starts, I want it to be executed when it ends instead, since the action itself may interfere with this process...

Comment: Processor resources and energy are of no concern for the application of my batch file, the loop lasts 2 sec max, and this is meant for desktop PCs exclusively.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
start /wait ProgramX.exe
rem "execute action N"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fit my purpose, since I need action N to be executed when the ProcessA.exe ends (I don't have any control over it), not the ProgramX.exe, it continues to ran through the whole process and beyond.